# Can you use the theory of Signal Space to study Band Base digital systems?

Tags: digital-communications, bandpass, baseband

**Introduction:**

There is one way to study different modulations in band pass digital systems and is working with "signal space" and the Constellation Diagram.

**My questions about this are:**

**1) Is it possible to apply it for band base systems?**

and if it's possible...

**2) How could i apply this to study band base digital systems?**

Thanks for the interest in this question

Comment: yes and read chapter 2 of this https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-451-principles-of-digital-communication-ii-spring-2005/readings-and-lecture-notes/MIT6_451S05_FullLecNotes.pdf

Comment: I really appreciate that but i have an exam on Monday. Is not being lazy but i do not have time to read everything. I just want a simple example to solidify some knowledge.

Comment: What i found out is this: To summarize, the key parameters of a band-limited continuous-time AWGN channel are its
bandwidth W in Hz and its signal-to-noise ratio SNR, regardless of other details like where the
bandwidth is located (in particular whether it is at baseband or passband),

Comment: It depends on how you define "key parameters". It is the same thing as what do you means in "studying baseband signal". You should as more specific questions.

Comment: Studying -> Analyze. We use the signal space theory to simplify and analyze different modulations (QPSK, BPSK, etc) and compare them. I am asking, if that could be applied for band base systems and a simple example in how to. I'm not asking for a full class but a simple explanation.

Comment: Honestly, I dont think the document I cited is not simple because it is just a lecture of a course. Sorry I cannot help.